# Does walking after eating really help with gas and constipation?

Tags: exercise, digestion

Does it really make any difference? If yes, then by what mechanism?

I pass gas frequently and have hard stools. I've read that walking helps with both these problems.

For example, on the [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/gas-and-gas-pains/in-depth/gas-and-gas-pains/art-20044739?pg=2) site, one of the recommendations is

> **Get moving**. It may help to take a short walk after eating.

That's all of it; there's no explanation why. I've seen similar advice on [other sites](http://www.drugs.com/cg/how-to-avoid-and-decrease-problems-with-gas.html) as well.

Is there any truth to this? And how does exercise affect constipation?

Answer (score 1):

[This '05 study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16028436) found a positive effect from exercise. Here middle aged (>45y) subjects with chronic idiopathic constipation had their Rome symptoms (straining, hard stools, and incomplete evacuation) improved by a 30 min cardio workout and 11 minute home programe.

On the other hand, this ['98 study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9824122) found there was little or no positive effect on patients with the same diagnosis, this study however, was smaller and of shorter duration.

However, I could find no study in favor (or against) of exercise helping *occasional* constipation. It is in the nature of this condition hard to gather subject for a controlled study, and we can assume the clinical support will stay at anecdotal level for some time being.

As exercise a lot of other benefits, it should in worst case be a harmless recommendation. Best case there is some effect that is not yet clinically documented.